# ASP.NET MVC Linq query for Left Outer Join with GroupBy multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

[image][image]I have tried this **Linq query** in my project which is based on Asp.net Mvc (5) having .Net Framework (4.7.2).

I am getting problem in **group by with multiple tables** query. How to write proper syntax of GroupBy condition using Linq? i am not getting desired result.

Here is my code.

```
var q = (from cc in _context.ClaimCommercials
     join cl in _context.Claims on cc.ClaimId equals cl.ClaimId
     join j in _context.Jobs on cl.JobId equals j.JobId
     join qu in _context.Quotations on j.QuotationId equals qu.QuotationId

     join cu in _context.Customers on qu.CustomerId equals cu.CustomerId into cust
     from cu in cust.DefaultIfEmpty()

     join insurance in _context.Customers on cc.InsuranceId equals insurance.CustomerId into insu
     from insurance in insu.DefaultIfEmpty()

     join importer in _context.Customers on cc.ImporterId equals importer.CustomerId into impor
     from importer in impor.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             
     select new StaticPrincipleReport
     {

}).ToList();
```

How to do a group by query for **cu**, **insurance** and **importer** in Linq.

Comment: Can you put an initial pattern of your tables with relationships?

Comment: What *problem* are you getting? An exception, or unexpected results? Please elaborate.

Comment: The problem is that I am getting an unexpected result .. Problem in Group by syntax in Linq Left join

Comment: GroupBy needs at least information about grouping keys and aggregations. Can you provide that?

Comment: @ Svyatoslav Danyliv i have shared the Keys with you in picture kindly check it..